# Multiple rows to single row in Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

As Azure DW is not supporting `FOR XML` and `SELECT` variable assignment, is there any other way to convert multiple rows into single row except using `CURSOR`?

Comment: Azure SQL DW does not support cursors either.  It does however support loops.  Have a look at this [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255719/parent-child-hierarchy-path-without-using-cte) I did for DW using string concatenation and loops.  Can you please post some sample data and expected results and I'll look at a SQL DW-specific solution.

Comment: Thanks bob. I have posted the query below which is working fine for me. Let me know if you have any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't found any direct method however the below code is working for me.

```
DECLARE @intColumnCount  INT, 
        @intProcessCount INT, 
        @varColList      VARCHAR(max) 

SET @varColList = '' 

IF Object_id('tempdb.dbo.#tempColumnNames') IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
      DROP TABLE #tempcolumnnames; 
  END 

CREATE TABLE #tempcolumnnames 
  ( 
     intid          INT, 
     varcolumnnames VARCHAR(256) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO #tempcolumnnames 
SELECT Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY NAME), 
       NAME 
FROM   sys.tables 

SET @intProcessCount = 1 
SET @intColumnCount = (SELECT Count(*) 
                       FROM   #tempcolumnnames) 

WHILE ( @intProcessCount <= @intColumnCount ) 
  BEGIN 
      SET @varColList = @varColList + ', ' 
                        + (SELECT varcolumnnames 
                           FROM   #tempcolumnnames 
                           WHERE  intid = @intProcessCount) 
      SET @intProcessCount +=1 
  END 

SELECT Stuff(@varColList, 1, 2, '')
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I would build in a loop safety : )

Comment: Honestly it's a bit confusing, the table is called `tempcolumnnames`, but appends table names.  Can I was what purpose does this code serve on your quite expensive 60-node MPP server?